# Trying to generate a python list of all values for any number of die rolls. Why is each value appended to multiple indexes in the returned list?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, probability

This is my attempt to make a function that generates every outcome of x die rolls. The fist list generated in the main function is [[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6]], and the replicated list is a list with that order of numbers repeated 6 times. Adding 1 to the first sixth, 2 to the second sixth, and so on will lead to a list with every outcome of rolling 2 (or more) die.

```
#Works for any number of sides on a dice
#Meant to expand the list to include an extra dice. The items needed for 1 
#dice is 6, for 2 die is 36, etc.
def replicate(x,y):
    new_lst = []
    for i in range(y):
        for k in x:
            new_lst.append(k)
    return new_lst

#Specifically for 6 sided die
def table_of_possibilities(x):
    or_lst = []
    for l in range(6):
        or_lst.append([l + 1])
    if x > 1:
        for k in range(x-1):
            lst = replicate(or_lst,6)
            length = len(lst)
            print(lst)
            #This list appears fine, lists of [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6] repeated 6 times
            for i in range(length):
                if i < length / 6:
                    lst[i].append(1)
                elif i < length / 3:
                    lst[i].append(2)
                elif i < length / 2:
                    lst[i].append(3)
                elif i < length * 2 / 3:
                    lst[i].append(4)
                elif i < length * 5 / 6:
                    lst[i].append(5)
                else:
                    lst[i].append(6)
    return lst

print(table_of_possibilities(2))
#The final list is the earlier print with 1,2,3,4,5,6 in each list
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to do but you can generate all die rolls using `itertools`, `itertools.product(range(1, 7), repeat=x)`

Comment: Isn't that exactly what you're trying to do, append each blue to each index in the returned list? It's unclear what you're asking. Can you give us your expected output, and the output you're getting? ie a MCVE?

Comment: The code returns this:[[1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], repeated 4 more times, while I want it to be [[1,1],[2,1],[3,1],[4,1],[5,1],[6,1],[1,2],[2,2] and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can deal with tuples, inside a list, then maybe itertools.product, as suggested, would suffice:

```
from itertools import product

myList = list(product(range(1,7), repeat=2)) # the second argument can be however
                                            # many die you want to roll.
print myList
```

In python 2.7 (what I am using), this returns:

[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 4), (4, 5), (4, 6), (5, 1), (5, 2), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5), (5, 6), (6, 1), (6, 2), (6, 3), (6, 4), (6, 5), (6, 6)]

more can be found here:
[9.7 itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html)

Comment: Thank you! I'd still like to know why my original code didn't work but this solved my problem.